# Is $x<\lvert x \rvert$ always true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know $x\leq \lvert x\rvert$ always is true.

But suppose it is a strict inequality,

$$x<\lvert x\rvert$$
is this also true?

*If $x\geq0$: then $\lvert x\rvert=x$.*

So $x<\lvert x\rvert=x \iff x<x \iff 0<0$.
**But what does $x<x$ and $0<0$ mean?**

*If $x<0$: then $\lvert x\rvert=-x$.*

So $x<-x \iff 2x<0 \iff x<0$. **True, I guess?**

Comment: If you have a strict inequality, then can $x$ be positive?

Comment: It is complete nonsense that $0<0$, which means you have reached a *contradiction*. Hence $x$ *cannot* be nonnegative.

Comment: `But what does x<x and 0<0 mean` Both are false. If that's not painfully obvious to you, please review the meaning of the "$\,\lt\,$" you use.

Comment: If you start with some assumptions and (without making any mistakes) deduce something absurd (like $x<x$) then don't worry about the absurdity. You just have proved then that at least one of the assumptions is false.

Answer (score 4):

> *If $x\geq0$: then $\lvert x\rvert=x$.*
>
> So $x<\lvert x\rvert=x \iff x<x \iff 0<0$. **But what does $x<x$ and $0<0$ mean?**

"$x \lt x$" is always false, including for $x=0\,$, because "$\,\lt\,$" is a [strict order relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Strict_and_non-strict_partial_orders), thus [irreflexive](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Irreflexive.html). Therefore $\,x \color{red}{\not\lt} |x|\,$ for $\,x \ge 0\,$.

> *If $x<0$: then $\lvert x\rvert=-x$.*
>
> So $x<-x \iff 2x<0 \iff x<0$. **True, I guess?**

True, indeed.

Combining the two cases above, all that can be said is that $\,x \lt |x| \,\iff\, x \lt 0\,$.

Comment: Thank you! Great links! A question regarding a little detail. In the first case we have the inequality, $x\geq0$, but we want to prove a strict inequality, $x<\lvert x\rvert$.
So in the proof I replace the absolute value with $x$, but should I also replace the strict inequality with an inequality?
I mean, should I write $x<x$ or $x\leq x$ (just because we are looking at the case $x\geq0$)?

Comment: @JDoeDoe `should I also replace the strict inequality with an inequality?` No. The two cases $x \ge 0$ and $x \lt 0$ are just the way you chose to break down the problem in easier-to-manage subcases. You could have as well chosen to break it down in three cases $x \gt 0\,$, $x = 0\,$ and $x \lt 0\,$ instead. But, no matter how you break it down, you still want to prove (or disprove) the same conclusion $x \lt |x|$ in all of those cases.